# web3.utils.sha3 and web3.sha3 are not returning same hash

Tags: hash, sha3

I am referring to example given in [link](https://kauri.io/a-deep-dive-into-the-ethereum-virtual-machine-evm/766e5d1e1ba240a7976943b659a871fc/a). I will summarize the steps given in the example to save your time from reading.

The example used below smart contract to demonstrate the web3.eth.getStorageAt() functionality. The author is explaining how to get the value of a storage of a mapping. He explained the example for persons[1]. The index of persons[1] is 2 and key is 1.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract StoreAge{

    /*
     * state variable `ages` storing a dynamic array of ages in 8 bits
     * state variable `oldest` storing the oldest age in 8 bits
     * state variable `persons` storing a mapping of number of persons to ages 
     */
    uint8 public oldest;
    
    uint8[] ages;
    
    mapping (uint8 => uint8) persons;
    
    constructor () public {
         oldest = 75;
         ages.push(20);
         ages.push(30);
         ages.push(56);
         persons[1] = 55; //1 person is 55
         persons[2] = 67; //2 persons are 67 
    }
}
```

He performed following steps and received the correct value. '0x37' = 55

```
$ truffle(develop)> n = ‘0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002’ 

$ truffle(develop)> p = '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001' 

$ truffle(develop)> first_item_addr = web3.sha3(n + p, {encoding: 'hex'}) 

$ '0xe90b7bceb6e7df5418fb78d8ee546e97c83a08bbccc01a0644d599ccd2a7c2e0'

$ truffle(develop)> web3.eth.getStorageAt(storeAge.address, first_item_addr) 

$ '0x37'
```

I performed the similar steps and getting 0x0.

```
$ truffle(develop)> n = ‘0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002’ 

$ truffle(develop)> p = '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001' 

$ truffle(develop)> first_item_addr = web3.utils.sha3(n + p, {encoding: 'hex'}) 

$ '0x1ccbca99b07224d036683c65d465d294a6c6f2dc5ff7f8844f276c36b2b5c988'

$ truffle(develop)> web3.eth.getStorageAt(storeAge.address, first_item_addr) 

$ '0x0'
```

I feel the hash function web3.utils.sha3 is not returning correct output. How can I get the correct output to fetch the storage of persons[1]? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try [web3.utils.soliditySha3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3).

Comment: i tried web3.utils.soliditySha3. But it is also giving different value.